# A chamuça é mesmo o pastel indiano?

Tags: etimologia, uso-de-palavras

Na minha família sempre chamámos de [chamuça](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/chamu%C3%A7a) a uma espécie de pastel, recheado de carne ou vegetais.

[image]

Mas ontem quando estive á procura de "chamuça" no google não tive quaisquer resultados associados a este pastel. [Já hoje não tive o mesmo problema](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=chamussa&espv=2&biw=1356&bih=715&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj64u3EsMHQAhXCAMAKHWGqAgIQ_AUIBSgA&dpr=1)

Este pastel pode ser denominado por outros nomes?
Qual é a origem da palavra "chamuça"?

Comment: Já agora, na Tailândia têm chamuças de banana. São fenomenais!!

Comment: @ANeves Isso é uma recomendacao para eu ir á Tailândia para as comer? xD

Comment: Faz o que for preciso... ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Sim**, em português esse pastel chama-se chamuça, e [segundo o dicionário](//priberam.pt/dlpo/chamu%C3%A7a) a palavra vem do hindi *samosa*:

> Pastel frito de massa folhada, de forma triangular, geralmente com recheio de carne picada e muito condimentado (ex.: chamuças vegetarianas).
>
> ---
>
> [https://priberam.pt/dlpo/chamuça](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/chamu%C3%A7a) - consultado em 24-11-2016

O artigo da Wikipédia inglesa sobre a chamuça fala da [etimologia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samosa#Etymology):

> A origam da palavra "samosa" pode ser seguida até ao *sanbosag* (Persa: سنبوساگ‎‎). O nome do pastel em outros países também deriva desta raíz, como o sanbusak ou sanbusaj no mundo árabe (que tem a forma de crescente), sambosa no Afeganistão, samosa na Índia, (Sindhi: سمبوسو Samboso/sambosa‎), samboosa no Tajiquistão, samsa nas nações que falam turco, sambusa no Corno de África, e chamuça em Goa, Moçambique e Portugal. Apesar de serem atualmente referidas por sambusak no mundo árabe, os livros de receitas medievais árabes por vezes chamam-nas de sambusaj.

O artigo da Wikipédia inglesa enumera ainda [os diversos nomes para a chamuça](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samosa#Name_variation), tudo variações da mesma palavra, com coisas tão diferentes como *somsa* e *sambusek*.